# script not activated by click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i am written some script in jquery and bind that to a click event, but the code do not get activated by click event. But when i put the script in another JavaScript function and bind that JavaScript function to click event listener than the function is able to execute on clicking.

Another thing is that when i bind the script using JavaScript it returns me alert message same number of time as the number of div on which i have clicked i.e. if i click on 3rd div the alert message is shown three times
on my page the dom structure is of pdf.js project and this dom is created dynamically
i want to get the index of grandchild of pagecontainer2 on which user had clicked
following is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".textLayer > div", "#pageContainer2").click(function () {
            var index = $(this).index();
            alert("index of div is = " + index);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Dom CODE :

```
<div id="pageContainer2" >
    <canvas id="page2" width="741" height="959"></canvas>
    <div class="textLayer">
        <div>......some text here....</div>
        <div>......some text here....</div>
        <div>......some text here....</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="pageContainer3" >
    <canvas id="page3" width="741" height="959"></canvas>
    <div class="textLayer">
        <div>......some text here....</div>
        <div>......some text here....</div>
        <div>......some text here....</div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Comment: Please give as your DOM (html code). And ask a question!

Comment: You need to make it more clear what your question is. You did a good job of explaining what is happening, now explain what you want to happen instead. :)

Comment: $(".textLayer > div , #pageContainer2")  use comma inside the quote marks

Comment: @jmort253 sir is my updated question is sufficient to clear what i want ??

Comment: I made a test and your code is ok, at least on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ptDzd/

Comment: @hiteshtr- I still don't get what you want to happen.

Comment: @hiteshtr - You still haven't explained what you are trying to do. You've just explained what is happening.  When asking a technical question, it's strongly suggested that you explain the behavior (which you've done a good job of) and also **explain what it is that you are trying to do**. You haven't explained what you want the code to do. For instance, when you click on the DIV, what is it that you expect to happen that is different from what is actually happening?

Comment: @rgin sir i want to get the index of grandchild of pagecontainer2 on which user had clicked

Comment: @mamoo sir i also tried it on jsfiddle its working fine but not on my page actually the dom structure is of pdf.js project and this dom is created dynamically

Comment: @jmort253 sir i want to get the index of div on which user clicked

Comment: @hiteshtr- include that fact in your question and see my edited answer.

Comment: The fact that the DOM is injected is of great importance, you should not miss such details on your question. Replace click() with live() or on() method, and try again... http://jqapi.com/#p=on

Comment: @mamoo- correct. Although, in newer versions, `live()` has been deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to assign a click event handler to a DOM node that is not yet present but will be created later, you need to bind the event handler to an existing node using `on` and specify the child nodes:

Let's say that `<div id="pageContainer2">` already exists, but you're creating those divs inside that container on the fly. So the proper sytnax would be:

```
$(function() {
    $('#pageContainer2').on('click', '.textlayer > div', function() {
        /* .... */
    });
});
```

That way, you're actually binding the event handler to the container, but since most events bubble up the DOM, an event fired by a click on any element inside that container will reach the container itself. Because you specified another selector (`.textlayer > div´), jQuery will then check if the actual element that got clicked on satisfies this selector.

If even #pageContainer2 is created after binding the event handler, you can still bind the event handler to the document itself:

```
$(document).on('click', '#pageContainer2 .textlayer > div', function() { ...
```

Comment: @isn't any way to do the same work with javascript if possible then provide it pls

Comment: sir thanx i modified ur code little bit and its working now perfectly

Answer (score 1):

try this javascript:

```
  $(function() {
        $(".textLayer").click(function () {
            var index = $(".textLayer").index(this);
            alert("index of div is = " + (index+1));
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one with slight modification...

```
$("#pageContainer2 > .textLayer > div").click(function () {
            var index = $(this).index();
            alert("index of div is = " + index);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the HTML is created dynamically, you will have to use the `on` API to bind your events.

```
$(function() {
   $(".textLayer > div", '#pageContainer2').on('click', function () {
       var index = $(this).index();
       alert("index of div is = " + index);
   });
});
```

Comment: but i only want get the index if div of textLayer belonging to pageContainer2

Comment: See you didn't mention that in your question. You should be as specific as possible when asking a question here, so people will be able to help you more quickly.

Comment: Check my updated answer, this should fix your problem now. :)

Comment: your above code is also not working don't know why can u provide me a way to do same thing with JavaScript if possible

Comment: At this point, I think it would be wise to post a link of your actual code as I cannot see how this would not work. Unless, you're, somehow, calling this script before the HTML is loaded.

Comment: i am developing the page offline but can i mail you my page if you are  comfortable to that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10155/discussion-between-rgin-and-hiteshtr)

Comment: @rgin `on` does not magically apply to not yet existing DOM nodes when you use it the way you're proposing. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @Niko- I'm not understanding you. Or is it that you did not see the asker's comments. I'm not proposing on binding events to non-existing DOM nodes, He said, `#pageContainer2` and its contents are being dynamically created, hence my suggestion.

Comment: @rgin I understand that, but there is absolutely no difference between `click(function)` and `on('click', function)` - so the code your providing does not differ from the code he originally posted.

Comment: @rgin i got the answer its following and thanx for ur time :
`$(function() {
        $('#viewer').on('dblclick','#pageContainer2 > .textLayer > div',function () {
            var index = $(this).index();
            alert("index of div is = " + index);
        });
    }); `

Comment: I see. You bind it to an existing element and just add the extra selectors later. Makes sense, I guess. Glad you found the answer.